# How to handle generated column in database table with Laravel Backpack?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-backpack, generated-columns

I have a table in a MySQL database that contains a virtual generated column. It is defined in the appropriate migration using ->virtualAs().

I've tweaked the Create and Update operations of the default CRUD controller that Backpack generated for me -- I've made the generated column read-only:

```
->attributes(['readonly'=>'readonly'])  // virtual generated column in the DB
```

That works great to keep the user from trying to change the value of the generated column when they're creating or updating an entry.

But it creates a problem when trying to save an entry you've just created. The SQL Insert statement crashes because the generated column is included in the Insert statement, vis:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3105 

The value specified for generated column 'type_subscr' in table 'subscriptions' is not allowed. 

(SQL: insert into `subscriptions` (`supporter_id_from`, `supporter_id_to`, `transaction_id`, `type_subscr`, 
`date_start`, `date_end`, `notes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (305, 2218, 14091, ?, 
2023-03-15 00:00:00, 2024-03-14 00:00:00, TEST DATA ONLY, 2023-03-15 18:33:36, 2023-03-15 18:33:36))
```

I think I need to tell the Create operation of the Backpack controller not to include `type_subscr` in the Insert statement at all. Is that the correct approach? How would I do that?

Or is there something I need to do in my Laravel model and/or migration that would solve the problem at *that* level, without having to tweak my Backpack controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `readonly`, you should use `disabled`:

```php
->attributes(['disabled'=>'disabled'])  // virtual generated column in the DB
```

The difference between `readonly` and `disabled` in HTML inputs (and Backpack too, by extension):

- `readonly` greys out the input, keeps sending the value;
- `disabled` greys out the input, no longer sends the value;